# IEquatables implementation only called if the base Equals is overridden

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following class

```
    class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        return Id.Equals(other.Id);
    }
}
```

If i try and create a unique list of the items of a list as follows

```
            Guid a = Guid.NewGuid();
        List<Product> listA = new List<Product>();
        listA.Add(new Product(){Id = a});

        List<Product> listB = new List<Product>();
        listB.Add(new Product()
        {
            Id = a
        });
        Debug.Assert(listA.Union(listB).Count()==1);
```

two items are returned, this occurs until I override the object.Equals method, once i do this and my code is as follows

```
class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return other.Id.Equals(Id);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (Product)) return false;
        return Equals((Product) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

my IEquatable Equals method is now called, but only if i override the base method, furthermore if i put a breakpoint on the object equals method it is never called.

Why is this?

----UPDATE

So with the product class

```
    class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        return Id.Equals(other.Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

If GetHashCode is removed, The IEquatable implementation of Equals is never hit I understand you should generally implement Equals and GetHashCode together, is this why?

Comment: Adding that `GetHashCode` implementation to your original class gets you the behaviour you want, it looks like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the original implementation you're not overriding the `GetHashcode` method.  Under the hood `Union` uses a `Set<T>` style structure to remove duplicates.  This structure puts objects into buckets based on the value returned from `GetHashCode`.  If the hash code doesnt't match up between equal objects (which it must do) then they can potentially be put in different buckets and never compared with `Equals`

In general if you implement `IEquatable<T>` you should always

- Override `Object.Equals`
- Override `Object.GetHashCode`

Not doing both will land you in situations like this.

Note, your implementation could be simplified a bit

```
class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public bool Equals(Product other) 
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) {
      return false;
    }
    return other.Id == this.Id;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) 
  {
    return Equals(obj as Product);
  }    

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return Id.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's just resharper's default implementation of the equals method. If this is the case, (and I am sure you are correct BTW) why does the breakpoint not get hit? Is that user error? Also the BOL here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx suggests that it should lookup IEquatable?

Comment: I am using the standard LINQ Union method, the code above is from a test harness to confirm what I am seeing

Comment: @KevHunter i've run this particular sample under the debugger and confirmed that the `override bool Equals` is never called in the sample.  It will always go through the `IEquatable<T>` version.  Have you ran this locally?

Comment: Adding the GetHashCode method as Aakash suggested gives me the behaviour I expect, any idea why this?

Comment: @KevHunter oh I didn't realize that in your original impl you didn't override `GetHashcode`.  Yse that's definitely a pre-req. The `Equals` method won't even be called if the hash codes don't match.

Comment: +1. From the documentaton it is not immediatly clear that IEquatable by itself is not enough - turns out you either need IEquatable<T> + GetHashCode, or better implement proper IEqualityComparer<T>.

Answer (score 4):

Documentation for [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) says:

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of
>   the types that implement the IEqualityComparer(Of T) generic
>   interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this
>   interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the
>   type.

You're implementing `IEquatable`. You need to implement `IEqualityComparer`.